# Streaming video using pyzmq

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, zeromq, pyzmq

I am using the Python bindings for zmq to send messages both between processes and across a network.  So far, no problem.  I now have an application where I want to stream data recovered from a small camera on a Raspberry Pi.  I have no issues actually recording the data but now I want to be able to stream that data.  I have an example on how to do this using the low level `sockets` api but would really like to use `zmq` for this application.

The `picamera` [documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream) has the example below on how to use a network stream to send data:

```
import socket
import time
import picamera

# Connect a client socket to my_server:8000 (change my_server to the
# hostname of your server)
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('my_server', 8000))

# Make a file-like object out of the connection
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (640, 480)
        camera.framerate = 24
        # Start a preview and let the camera warm up for 2 seconds
        camera.start_preview()
        time.sleep(2)
        # Start recording, sending the output to the connection for 60
        # seconds, then stop
        camera.start_recording(connection, format='h264')
        camera.wait_recording(60)
        camera.stop_recording()
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

`zmq` does not implement a `buffer` interface, so you can not simply change the `socket` object for a `zmq.Context()` object.  I feel like this should be relatively simple, but have been unable to find any information on this.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to use the `zmq` api in this case?

Comment: zmq is not really geared towards this, its for passing messages really. There are new socket types in 4.2 RADIO/DISH, which I believe you can use to do UDP . Dont quote me on that thoguh

Comment: can just use normal python UDP sockets to stream the cam video, if thats all you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, reptilicus - I think that you have hit the nail on the head.  From the guide

> It gives you sockets that carry atomic messages ...

It does look like zerorpc might be the direction I want to go though.

Answer (score 0):

### RPi side: `picamera.PiCamera()` API rulez:

Besides the file-based output, RPi has another alternative for the **`output`** attribute, worth a try.

> [If output is not a **`string`**, but is an object with a **`write()`** method, it is assumed to be a file-like object and the video data is appended to it (the implementation only assumes the object has a `write()` method - no other methods are required but **`flush()`** will be called at the end of recording if it is present).
>
> If output is not a `string`, and has no `write()` method it is assumed to be a writeable object implementing the buffer protocol. In this case, the video frames will be written sequentially to the underlying buffer (which must be large enough to accept all frame data).](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/api_camera.html)

### So?

The most straight forward way is to create a Class for interfacing objects, equipped with both the **`.write()`** and **`.flush()`** methods, that would transfer the relevant video-data towards the messaging zmq-sockets ( may have more than just the one trivial **`PUB/SUB`** archetype, so as to have Out-of-Band signalling and similar nice features coming from ZeroMQ Scaleable Formal Communications Framework ) that were instantiated under the central `zmq.Context()`.

### Performance?

If running into doubts about IO-performance, there are steps that could be done on the ZeroMQ side -- instantiate the central I/O-pumping `Context` with more than just a single I/O-thread by `zmq.Context( numOfIOthreads )` and perhaps decide on using sort of balancing steps with different **`AFFINITY`** settings in instantiated `aSocketINSTANCE.setsockopt()` so as to "reserve" some relative I/O-priorities among the respective instances, pre-reserving the shared-resources in respective manner to protect some minimum levels of access to I/O-threads as needed in your design's performance requirements ( until hardware can support and benefit from those levels of concurrency ).